# GCM remote notifications & azure

Tags: c#, azure, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android

I am currently developping an application who will receive notification from an azure hub notification.

I follow this two tutorials :

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/
https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/

The registration succeed in the android app ( in emulator ), i get the token id but when i try to send a test notification, I receive nothing :

Here the notification sample in azure :
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Looks like you are sending to a topic "/topics/global" however is your client application subscribing to the global topic?

Comment: Yes, i follow the tutorial and it use the global topic

Comment: Does azure provide the response when you send the message?

Comment: yes, but the response say 0 success 0 fault, i found this tutorial today but i did not have the time to do it, i will back if this tutorial is better : https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/push-notifications-with-xamarin-android/

Comment: Success 0  would indicate that no clients are subscribed to the "/topics/global" topic. So I'd look at the client and make sure this is the case. Also you could try sending directly to the token, then try topic.

Comment: I did the both, and nothin happen, my client register corretly